# Facebook and GoogleAnalytics is causing Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)

Tags: android, multithreading, facebook-android-sdk

I'm getting this exception on each connection done to facebook while using their Android SDK.
Also GAThread from EasyTracker is also generating this exact problem.

```
6960-6985/? A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 6985 (Timer-0)
608-669/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '42867090 com.packagename/com.packagename.activities.feed.FeedActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: have you fixed this issue?

Comment: did not, turned off the GAThread, and I keep living with Facebook issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi I had a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486932/app-crash-when-requesting-friend-list). My issue was caused by SSL management of [OkHTTP](http://square.github.io/okhttp/).
Take a look at [this bug issue](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/184) on OkHTTP's github page

My workaround (they say that it will be fixed with v2.0) is this:

```
URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new OkHttpClient());
```

**UPDATED: Square has release OkHTTP v1.5.0 and they s[hould have fixed](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#okhttp-no-longer-uses-the-default-ssl-context) the SSL issue.**

> Applications that want to use the global SSL context with OkHttp
>   should configure their OkHttpClient instances with the following:
>
> ```
> okHttpClient.setSslSocketFactory(HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory());
> ```
>
> A simpler solution is to avoid the shared default SSL socket factory.
>   Instead, if you need to customize SSL, do so for your specific
>   OkHttpClient instance only.

Comment: that is it man. Many thanks for this solution, if you happen to be on Droidcon in Berlin send me a priv msg would like to get you a beer for that.

Comment: Ahahaha I would really like to grab that beer with you. It took me 4 day of debugging without understanding the problem. I will be at droidcon in Turin this week :-)

Comment: where do I implement this code when using the Phonegap

Answer (score 0):

Got the same app crash when launching the ShareDialog from the Facebook Android Library.
I'm using retrofit and okhttp.
Upgrading to the current versions of both in my gradle file solved the problem:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1'
```