# App crash when requesting friend list

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I got a really strange crash.

User login into the app correctly. 
I'm correctly calling all UiLifecycleHelper methods into my code.

When I try to perfrom a simple request (get the user's friends list) my app crash in a brutal way.

Here the function that make the app crash:

```
private void fetchUserFriends() {
    //Gather all friend list
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if( session != null && session.isOpened() ) {
        Request.newMyFriendsRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response) {
                if (response.getError() == null) {
                    //use all friends
                } else {
                    //print error
                }
            }
        }).executeAsync();
    }
}
```

I've digged a little bit and it seems that the instruction that is making the whole app crash EVERY TIME is this:

`connection.getResponseCode()` that internally is doing `connection.getInputStream()`

Here you are with the Facebook reference: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/Response.java?source=cc#L301

And here's the crash log:

```
    01-31 18:57:34.866  16008-16157/com.myapp.example A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 16157 (AsyncTask #1)
01-31 18:57:34.966      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-31 18:57:34.966      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ Build fingerprint: 'google/hammerhead/hammerhead:4.4.2/KOT49H/937116:user/release-keys'
01-31 18:57:34.966      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ Revision: '11'
01-31 18:57:34.966      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ pid: 16008, tid: 16157, name: AsyncTask #1  >>> com.myapp.example <<<
01-31 18:57:34.966      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.036      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 7878a085  r3 00000017
01-31 18:57:35.036      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ r4 00000006  r5 7878a086  r6 00000000  r7 ffffffff
01-31 18:57:35.036      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ r8 00000001  r9 40ad6130  sl 00000017  fp 7878a085
01-31 18:57:35.036      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ ip 744c4b34  sp 78d82990  lr 744b909d  pc 40ac0f2e  cpsr 600e0030
01-31 18:57:35.036      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
01-31 18:57:35.036      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
01-31 18:57:35.036      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ d4  36201920e71141ae  d5  d79404659c7eaae1
01-31 18:57:35.036      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ d6  5f1ab8125a9713ab  d7  2af5aac9dc89c133
01-31 18:57:35.036      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
01-31 18:57:35.036      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
01-31 18:57:35.036      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
01-31 18:57:35.036      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
01-31 18:57:35.036      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ d16 0000000000000000  d17 0000000000000000
01-31 18:57:35.036      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ d18 4839349042576f78  d19 e71141aeb758fe2b
01-31 18:57:35.036      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ d20 c047800000000000  d21 c060800000000000
01-31 18:57:35.036      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ d22 0000000000000000  d23 c047800000000000
01-31 18:57:35.036      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
01-31 18:57:35.036      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ d26 3ff0000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
01-31 18:57:35.036      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ d28 3ff0000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
01-31 18:57:35.036      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ d30 0000000000000000  d31 c060800000000000
01-31 18:57:35.036      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ scr 60000012
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ backtrace:
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00  pc 00026f2e  /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_select_next_proto+49)
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01  pc 00007099  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02  pc 0002f2f3  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl_parse_serverhello_tlsext+434)
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ #03  pc 0001810d  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl3_get_server_hello+1004)
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ #04  pc 00017517  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl3_connect+566)
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ #05  pc 00027ccb  /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_do_handshake+50)
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ #06  pc 0000aeb3  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ #07  pc 0001dbcc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ #08  pc 0004e123  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ #09  pc 00026fe0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ #10  pc 0002dfa0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ #11  pc 0002b638  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ #12  pc 00060581  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ #13  pc 000605a5  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ #14  pc 0005528b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ #15  pc 0000d170  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ #16  pc 0000d308  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ stack:
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82950  1e43b5c6
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82954  e20d00d8
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82958  00000002
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d8295c  744b8fd5  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82960  00000002
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82964  744b8fd5  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82968  40a6bf6c  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d8296c  40a0a8fd  /system/lib/libcrypto.so (CRYPTO_lock+40)
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82970  75b198f8  [anon:libc_malloc]
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82974  00000000
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82978  00000000
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d8297c  000070a4
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82980  00000002
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82984  744b8fd5  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82988  00000002
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d8298c  744b8fd5  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00  78d82990  40a6bf6c  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82994  78d82a10  [stack:16157]
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82998  78d82a0c  [stack:16157]
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d8299c  7878a085  [anon:libc_malloc]
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d829a0  00000017
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d829a4  7878a085  [anon:libc_malloc]
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d829a8  78501888  [anon:libc_malloc]
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d829ac  78d82a0c  [stack:16157]
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d829b0  78d82a10  [stack:16157]
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d829b4  75a92d68  [anon:libc_malloc]
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d829b8  40ad6130  /system/lib/libssl.so
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d829bc  00000017
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d829c0  7878a081  [anon:libc_malloc]
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d829c4  744b909d  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01  78d829c8  00000000
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d829cc  ffffffff
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d829d0  7878a09c  [anon:libc_malloc]
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d829d4  78d82a48  [stack:16157]
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d829d8  78d82a48  [stack:16157]
01-31 18:57:35.046      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d829dc  7878a085  [anon:libc_malloc]
01-31 18:57:35.056      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d829e0  00003374
01-31 18:57:35.056      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d829e4  40ac92f5  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl_parse_serverhello_tlsext+436)
01-31 18:57:35.056      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02  78d829e8  00000017
01-31 18:57:35.056      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d829ec  00000000
01-31 18:57:35.056      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d829f0  40ad15a5  /system/lib/libssl.so
01-31 18:57:35.056      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d829f4  00000000
01-31 18:57:35.056      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d829f8  00000001
01-31 18:57:35.056      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d829fc  78d82a4c  [stack:16157]
01-31 18:57:35.056      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82a00  7878a098  [anon:libc_malloc]
01-31 18:57:35.056      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82a04  7878a09c  [anon:libc_malloc]
01-31 18:57:35.056      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82a08  75a92d68  [anon:libc_malloc]
01-31 18:57:35.056      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82a0c  75a92f58  [anon:libc_malloc]
01-31 18:57:35.056      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82a10  40a8edc0  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
01-31 18:57:35.056      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82a14  75a92d68  [anon:libc_malloc]
01-31 18:57:35.056      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82a18  00000068
01-31 18:57:35.056      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82a1c  7878a034  [anon:libc_malloc]
01-31 18:57:35.056      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82a20  75a17078  [anon:libc_malloc]
01-31 18:57:35.056      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82a24  7878a057  [anon:libc_malloc]
01-31 18:57:35.056      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ ........  ........
01-31 18:57:35.056      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near r2:
01-31 18:57:35.056      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a064 b8125a97 c1335f1a aac9dc89 23002af5
01-31 18:57:35.056      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a074 c08d7bf1 20000011 010001ff 00743300
01-31 18:57:35.056      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a084 70730617 332f7964 64707306 08322f79
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a094 70747468 312e312f 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a0a4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a0b4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a0c4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a0d4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a0e4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a0f4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a104 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a114 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a124 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a134 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a144 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a154 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near r5:
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a064 b8125a97 c1335f1a aac9dc89 23002af5
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a074 c08d7bf1 20000011 010001ff 00743300
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a084 70730617 332f7964 64707306 08322f79
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a094 70747468 312e312f 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a0a4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a0b4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a0c4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a0d4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a0e4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a0f4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a104 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a114 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a124 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a134 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a144 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a154 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near r9:
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ad6110 00000001 00000020 00000002 00000002
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ad6120 00000105 0000c030 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ad6130 00000001 40acc60f 0300c011 00000080
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ad6140 00000001 00000004 00000002 00000002
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ad6150 00000041 0000c030 00000080 00000080
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ad6160 00000001 40acc621 0300c012 00000080
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ad6170 00000001 00000002 00000002 00000002
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ad6180 00000181 0000c030 000000a8 000000a8
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ad6190 00000001 40acc638 0300c013 00000080
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ad61a0 00000001 00000040 00000002 00000002
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ad61b0 00000181 0000c030 00000080 00000080
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ad61c0 00000001 40acc64d 0300c014 00000080
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ad61d0 00000001 00000080 00000002 00000002
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ad61e0 00000181 0000c030 00000100 00000100
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ad61f0 00000001 40acc662 0300c015 00000080
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ad6200 00000004 00000020 00000002 00000002
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near fp:
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a064 b8125a97 c1335f1a aac9dc89 23002af5
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a074 c08d7bf1 20000011 010001ff 00743300
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a084 70730617 332f7964 64707306 08322f79
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a094 70747468 312e312f 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a0a4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a0b4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a0c4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a0d4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a0e4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a0f4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a104 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a114 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a124 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a134 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a144 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7878a154 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near ip:
01-31 18:57:35.066      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744c4b14 40a266e1 409eaaf9 40a1cd21 40a1c9c5
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744c4b24 40a1d70d 40a159cd 40a20d41 400f2021
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744c4b34 40ac0efd 400ed7dc 400ed8e0 40a34091
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744c4b44 40ac0775 4013a927 400db3b1 402b35b5
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744c4b54 40a2919d 40a21a49 40a218b5 40a21851
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744c4b64 40a21dd9 40a23ec9 40104235 40a23ea9
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744c4b74 40a23f8d 400ecc01 400f2415 400f0ef5
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744c4b84 402b36f5 40ac0f79 40ac3e9d 40a5bbfd
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744c4b94 409f45f5 409f46dd 40a5bc45 409f7799
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744c4ba4 409eda29 409f025d 40a5b385 40a4eef9
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744c4bb4 409f62f5 409f9a5d 40a29ad9 409f9b01
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744c4bc4 409e9905 40a2a135 40a19f01 40a1a265
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744c4bd4 40a19a5d 40a19c69 40a1a09d 40a199d9
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744c4be4 40a19e8d 40a33f39 40a19e99 40a19e91
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744c4bf4 40a19d6d 40a2b839 40a2b73d 40a2bb79
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744c4c04 409eab01 40a1a365 409e89a1 409f3b61
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near sp:
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82970 75b198f8 00000000 00000000 000070a4
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82980 00000002 744b8fd5 00000002 744b8fd5
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82990 40a6bf6c 78d82a10 78d82a0c 7878a085
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d829a0 00000017 7878a085 78501888 78d82a0c
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d829b0 78d82a10 75a92d68 40ad6130 00000017
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d829c0 7878a081 744b909d 00000000 ffffffff
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d829d0 7878a09c 78d82a48 78d82a48 7878a085
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d829e0 00003374 40ac92f5 00000017 00000000
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d829f0 40ad15a5 00000000 00000001 78d82a4c
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82a00 7878a098 7878a09c 75a92d68 75a92f58
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82a10 40a8edc0 75a92d68 00000068 7878a034
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82a20 75a17078 7878a057 40ad6130 00000020
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82a30 00001110 40ab2111 78d82a48 78d82a44
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82a40 75a92d68 00000001 78501888 7878a07a
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82a50 75a92d68 00001120 78501888 744b91fd
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 78d82a60 00000000 00001120 00001000 40ab151b
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ code around pc:
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ac0f0c d02c2b00 9f0f9701 21009102 4001f81b
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ac0f1c 0801f101 eb0bb1cf eb0b0001 90030508
01-31 18:57:35.076      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ac0f2c f8162000 f1009000 454c0a01 eb06d109
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ac0f3c 4628010a f7e54622 4601ef8c 29002001
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ac0f4c eb0ad00a 42b80009 eb08d3eb 9a040104
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ac0f5c 42912002 e000d3da 99029e03 1c729f01
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ac0f6c 7832603a b005700a 8ff0e8bd 3178f8d0
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ac0f7c 2100600b bf182b00 117cf890 47706011
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ac0f8c 11a4f8c0 21a8f8c0 bf004770 11acf8c0
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ac0f9c 21b0f8c0 bf004770 4605b570 f8d54614
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ac0fac 460e01bc bf182800 ee02f7e5 f240480a
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ac0fbc 490a6296 44014478 f7e54620 2101edee
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ac0fcc 01bcf8c5 4631b130 f7e54622 2100ee2e
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ac0fdc 41c0f8c5 bd704608 00013a84 ffffb5ae
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ac0fec 4605b570 f8d54614 460e019c bf182800
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40ac0ffc eddef7e5 f240480a 490a62aa 44014478
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ code around lr:
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744b907c 46052121 f7fe4640 6a6aef98 b13c6aab
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744b908c 000ce88d 46314638 9b084622 ef74f7fe
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744b909c e8bd2000 b53881fc b1884604 b1556a05
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744b90ac ffccf7ff 68036829 47906d9a f7fe4628
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744b90bc 2000ef82 21006220 60e12001 bd386161
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744b90cc b508bd38 6d5a6803 bd084790 6803b508
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744b90dc 47906dda b508bd08 6fda6803 bd084790
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744b90ec 6804b510 4084f8d4 bd1047a0 b513b40c
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744b90fc 6804ab04 2b04f853 40c8f8d4 47a09301
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744b910c 401ce8bd 4770b002 b513b40c 6804ab04
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744b911c 2b04f853 40f8f8d4 47a09301 401ce8bd
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744b912c 4770b002 b513b40c 6804ab04 2b04f853
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744b913c 41ccf8d4 47a09301 401ce8bd 4770b002
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744b914c 6803b508 229cf8d3 bd084790 6803b508
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744b915c 22acf8d3 bd084790 6804b510 42b0f8d4
01-31 18:57:35.086      179-179/? I/DEBUG﹕ 744b916c bd1047a0 6803b508 32b4f8d3 bd084798
01-31 18:57:35.316      779-836/? I/BootReceiver﹕ Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_02 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
01-31 18:57:35.316    779-16174/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.myapp.example/.ui.activity.BuilderActivity
01-31 18:57:35.346     779-1160/? I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{43688bd8 u0 com.myapp.example/com.myapp.example.ui.activity.FeedActivity}
01-31 18:57:35.346      779-850/? W/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '4379edc0 com.myapp.example/com.myapp.example.ui.activity.BuilderActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
01-31 18:57:35.346      779-850/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '4379edc0 com.myapp.example/com.myapp.example.ui.activity.BuilderActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
01-31 18:57:35.346    779-22384/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Process com.myapp.example (pid 16008) has died.
01-31 18:57:35.356     779-1162/? W/InputDispatcher﹕ Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '4379edc0 com.myapp.example/com.myapp.example.ui.activity.BuilderActivity (server)'
01-31 18:57:35.356     779-1162/? I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{4379edc0 u0 com.myapp.example/com.myapp.example.ui.activity.BuilderActivity}
01-31 18:57:35.356    779-22384/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force removing ActivityRecord{42db95f0 u0 com.myapp.example/.ui.activity.FeedActivity t525}: app died, no saved state
01-31 18:57:35.366      182-182/? D/Zygote﹕ Process 16008 terminated by signal (11)
01-31 18:59:36.526    1055-7961/? W/Binder﹕ Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.setSessionEnabled(IInputMethodWrapper.java:280)
            at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethod$Stub.onTransact(IInputMethod.java:129)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

It's a really strange bug and it crashes ALL the time. Do you know how to fix it?

**UPDATE with the full scenario**

This is the scenario. 
I go into my fb account and delete my app from my application's permission list to have clean environment. After that I install my app and connect to facebook and make a "get fb friends request" everything works as intended.
If I close my app and try it again and make the same request it crashes on the connection.getInputStream (as described in the middle of the question).

Comment: I've updated the question. As you can see the request is pretty simple.

Comment: Any reason you're getting the Session a second time? It might be null. You should pass in to `newMyFriendsRequest` the session variable you've already retrieved.

Comment: You're right but I don't think that that is the problem.

Comment: I've updated my question with more details and the scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to take a look at this OkHttp issue:

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/184

I had a similar problem with Google Analytics because OkHttp changes the global SSL context. Removing OkHttp fixed my issue, can you try to copy and paste your code on a different project with no external libs?

Comment: If you are correct this will sucks a lot. I would really like to use okhttp with Picasso :-(

Comment: URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new OkHttpClient()); fixed my problem (this is just a workaround waiting OkHTTP 2.0 with real fix)